# Appcelerator 4.0.1 & TableView on Android

Tags: android, tableview, appcelerator

Hi I'm a beginner with Appcelerator Studio and I'm trying to make a simple app with a simple tableview.
I'm trying to do this in various OS. The results is that is working well just only on Mac OS X with iphone emulator. On windows 8.1 and on Ubuntu 14.04, running app on Android emulator, I have the same problem: app starts but don't show the data table but just a blank window!

I have an index.xml like this:

```
<Alloy>
    <Window class="container">
        <TableView id="list" onClick="onClick" top="50px"></TableView>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

and a index.js file like this:

```
// list
var items = [{
    title : "html.it",
    url : "http://www.html.it"
}, {
    title : "google",
    url : "http://www.google.com"
}, {
    title : "facebook",
    url : "http://www.facebook.com"
}];

// tableview data binding
$.list.data = items;

// callback associata al click
function onClick(e) {
    Ti.API.info(JSON.stringify(e));
    alert("clicked on row " + e.index + "\n" + items[e.index].url);
}

$.index.open();
```

Can someone help me understand why table does not appear?
I did the tests with Android 4.4.2 and Android 5 too

Answer (score 0):

here the problem description and how to avoid it..
https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-19064